# What does "Refresh resources upon completion" do exactly?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have been searching for a while online, since I don't exactly understand what "refresh resources" exactly mean? What are exactly "resources" in this case, and what does selecting that check box do (Refresh resources upon completion)?
I know when you build your project, your source files gets compiled and dependencies gets downloaded/installed into the local machine .m2 repository, if they need to. But I don't know what does "refreshing resources" in this case mean. What does it do exactly? I am not sure what does the "refresh" (when you right click a project and say "refresh") do either? Are they the same?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Resources are files and folders in your workspace. Normally Eclipse does not check if something outside of the Eclipse code changes these resources and when it does finally notice it will give an error message out the resource being out of synchronization.

'Something outside of Eclipse' means any code that does not use the Eclipse resource APIs (`IFile` and the like) to create and change files. So, for example, running an external builder might change files without Eclipse seeing the changes.

Selecting `refresh resources` causes Eclipse to check for changes and to update its information about the resources to match.

This is the same as using the `Refresh` menu option.

There is also an option `Refresh using native hooks or polling` in `Preferences > General > Workspace` which tries to deal automatically with these changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "something outside of the Eclipse"? Would you elaborate?

Comment: Elaborated, also added Preference options.